# Attachment Excel File from Stream in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, email, stream

I have an excel document.I want to mail it as attachment from stream.

It sended mail with attachment but i cant open excel file correctly

this is my code:

```
public static string EPostaGonder(...,Stream AttachmentStream,string AttachmentFileName)
    {
      .
      .
      .
       SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient(Host, Port);
       mailClient.EnableSsl = true;
       NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential(KullaniciAdi, Sifre);
       mailClient.Credentials = cred;

       MailMessage ePosta = new MailMessage();
       ePosta.IsBodyHtml = true;
       ePosta.From = new MailAddress(Kimden, Isim);
       foreach (string Kime_ in Kime.Split(';'))
       {
         if (Kime_.Trim() != "")
            ePosta.To.Add(Kime_.Trim());


       ePosta.Subject = Konu;
       ePosta.Body = Mesaj.Replace("\n","<br/>");
       if (Cc != "")
         ePosta.CC.Add(Cc);

       if (AttachmentStream != null)
          {
             AttachmentStream .Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);                 
             ePosta.Attachments.Add(
                      new Attachment(AttachmentStream, AttachmentFileName + ".xlsx"));
          }


        try
        {
           //mailClient.SendAsync(ePosta, (object)ePosta);
           mailClient.Send(ePosta);

             return "Done";
        }
         catch (SmtpException SmtpException_)
         {
             return SmtpException_.Message;
         }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following code to add Attachment in mail. Simply pass the file path to Attachment constructor.

```
Attachment attachment = new Attachment(file);
ePosta.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

**Add an attachment from stream:**

```
ePosta.Attachments.Add( new Attachment( AttachmentStream, filename, "application/msexcel" ));
```

Comment: check the post to add attachment from stream.

Comment: @stack you are creating file on disk, so you have to remove it manually. Is there any option to create file in memory stream and use that as attachment.

Comment: @RomilKumarJain: Option means ?? DO I need to create it everytime for each user ? Let me know if you know any other way.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
var attach = new MailAttachment(Server.MapPath(strFileName));
ePosta.Attachments.Add(attach);
```

Have a look at this article about [ASP.NET email with multiple attachments](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8528/ASP-NET-email-with-multiple-attachments)